# Sequelize Connection pool reading wrong database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to utilize sequelize connection pool option

Here is what I am trying [documentation link](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/read-replication/#:%7E:text=Sequelize%20uses%20a%20pool%20to,query%20will%20use%20write%20pool.)

```
    const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, null, {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: 3306,
  replication: {
    read: [
      { host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: 'password', database: 'test' },
    ],
    write: { host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: 'password', database: 'test1' },
  }
});

module.exports.sequelize = sequelize;
```

The expected behavior here should be, that all Read calls should be made from 'read' option and all write operations should be done on 'write' option ie.
**Read from "test" DB and write to "test1"**

Here is a sample route I am testing with,

```
app.get('/',async function(req,res){
    const [ readRes ] = await sequelize.query("select * from users");
    const writeRes = await sequelize.query("insert into users(name,status) values('user11',1)");
    const [readRes1 ] = await sequelize.query("select * from users");
    res.send([
        { response1 : readRes }
    ]);
});
```

In the above example, the output for the readRes and readRes1 is always from the 'test1' DB ie write DB.

In fact, the write operations are working as expected but the read operation are always reading from "write" DB instead of "readdb"

If i swap out test1 DB as read and test as write DB then also all read operations happen on read DB.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

So, It turn out to be a very silly mistate. I was not passing the query type parameter to the query.

After reading a bit here on [thread](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9971#issuecomment-432945961), it clicked to me!

So the code should have been.

```
app.get('/',async function(req,res){
    const [ readRes ] = await sequelize.query("select * from users",{ type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
    const writeRes = await sequelize.query("insert into users(name,status) values('user11',1)");
    const [readRes1 ] = await sequelize.query("select * from users",{ type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
    res.send([
        { response1 : readRes }
    ]);
});
```

Notice the **{ type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }** You need to be explicit about your query type. My assumtion was based on tyep of operation (Insert/Update/Select) the lib could figure out and will set the appropriate type.

They should have highlighted it in documentation like they did it for other option.

> Each write or useMaster: true query will use write pool. For SELECT
> read pool will be used. Read replica are switched using a basic round
> robin scheduling.